# Layout preview not showing ActionBar overflow options

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a slight issue here where the overflow options for the `ActionBar` are showing up in the emulator but not the layout preview. I'm currently using Android Studio v 2.1.3.

Has anyone else come across the same issue?

**Layout Preview**

[image]

**Emulator Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your layout file, add the `tools:menu` attribute directly to the `Toolbar` widget:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:menu="@menu/your_menu"/>
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#toolsmenu):

> **tools:menu**
>
> *Intended for: Any root `<View>`*
>
> This attribute specifies which menu the layout preview should show in
>   the app bar. The value can be one or more menu IDs, separated by
>   commas (without @menu/ or any such ID prefix and without the .xml
>   extension).

However, I find that it only works if:

1. the attribute is added directly to the `Toolbar` widget
2. the value includes the `@menu/` prefix

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `tools:menu` to your root view in the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:menu="menu1,menu2" />
```

more info here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes

Comment: unfortunately that didn't fix the issue for me. I've also tried changing the theme but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Just tried changing the min-SDK, rebuild and clearing cache. Problem still persists.

Comment: I did the same according to the official documentation. Sadly, it didn't work