# How to set or preview a toolbar menu from XML

Tags: android, toolbar

I would like to see the toolbar menu from Design view. Is there any `tool` for that?

At the moment I set the toolbar menu from code like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.search_menu);
```

Comment: Many of times, you have to select the right Theme in the Design View.

Comment: You can't _set_ the menu from XML afaik, but you can preview it with `tools:menu="@menu/your_menu"` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56406468/11566289)